# plotting a cumulative frequency curve on a histogram in R

Tags: r, plot, histogram, axis, curve

I would like to plot a cumulative frequency curve on a histogram and while I managed to draw actually the two plots correctly, I cannot make the second axis work in the correct scale(cumulative frequency percentage). This is what I did, but I am getting a range of 0 to 600 in my second y axis..Could you please help me with this? What am I doing wrong?

```
hist(all_final_braking_events$Mean)->h
plot(h, col="red")
par(new=TRUE)
all_final_braking_events$Mean->y
plot(sort(y), 1:length(y), xaxt="n", yaxt="n", ann=FALSE)
axis(side=4, ylim=c(0,100), las=1)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question, if it asks for a histogram density plot or if it asks for a frequencies histogram with a cumulative relative frequencies line.

First some data, since there is none in the question.

```
set.seed(2021)    # Make the results reproducible
n <- 1e4
x <- rgamma(n, shape = 10, scale = 0.5)
```

### 1. Density and frequencies plots

The two plots that follow are a density, to the left, and a frequencies plot, to the right, with cumulative density and frequencies lines, respectively.
Note graphics parameter `ylim` settings on both plots.

```
old_par <- par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

h <- hist(x, freq = FALSE, col = "red", ylim = c(0, 1))
lines(h$mids, cumsum(h$density))

h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
plot(h, col = "red", ylim = c(0, sum(h$counts)))
lines(h$mids, cumsum(h$counts))

par(old_par)
```

[image]

### 2. Frequencies plot with relative frequencies line.

Now a plot of frequencies with a cumulative relative frequencies line superimposed and its second axis to the right of the plot.

The second axis positions are cumulative *frequencies* but its labels are cumulative relative frequencies (*density*).

Note the `ylim` graphic parameter set to the sum of the frequencies.

```
h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
plot(h, col = "red", ylim = c(0, sum(h$counts)))
lines(h$mids, cumsum(h$counts))
axis(
  side = 4,
  at = pretty(cumsum(h$counts)),
  labels = pretty(cumsum(h$density))
)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your swift response! It is the second case that I want to plot. Applying your code I am getting this error : Error in axis(side = 4, at = pretty(cumsum(h$counts)), labels = pretty(cumsum(h$density))) : 
  'at' and 'labels' lengths differ, 8 != 6

Comment: @Evi-Evan You forgot to post the error :)

Comment: I am also trying that:     hist(all_final_braking_events$Mean)->h
plot(h, col="pink")
par(new=TRUE)
all_final_braking_events$Mean->y
plot(sort(y), 1:length(y), xaxt="n", yaxt="n", ann=FALSE)
f=cumsum(h$counts)
axis(side=4, at = pretty(f),labels = pretty(f)) that works, but gives me again not the correct scale for my y axis! I have tried multiplying with 100 and divide with the number of sample (n) but again i am getting just counts on second y axis...

Comment: do you have any suggestions for the error I am getting? I tried also changing the ticks in the axis, but no luck :( .